# Difference between two dates including the first and last day in JS

Tags: node.js, momentjs

i have two dates, where the first one is the date start and the second one is the date end.

I have to translate this in number of Years, Months and Days.

Example:

```
    const start = moment(new Date('2021-03-03'))
    const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03'))
    const difference = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
    const days = difference.days() //30
    const months = difference.months() // 11
    const years = difference.years() // 0
```

the result is:

```
{"days":30,"months":11,"years":0}
```

But my expected behavior is:

```
{"days":0,"months":0,"years":1}
```

How can I reach this?

Comment: You can try this simple & clean way `const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03')).add('1', 'days')` to achieve your goal. Have a look on my solution i have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your expected behavior just simply change your code:

from this:

`const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03'))`

to this:

`const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03')).add('1', 'days')`

This will give: `{"days":0,"months":0,"years":1}`

Final full updated code:

```
const start = moment(new Date('2021-03-03'))
const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03')).add('1', 'days')
const difference = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
const days = difference.days() // 0
const months = difference.months() // 0
const years = difference.years() // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because at 03/03 it will always remain at least a millisecond to complete the year.

For example i try to use `.startOf('d')` and `.endOf('d')` and this is the results:

```
const start = moment(new Date('2021-03-03')).startOf('d')
const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03')).endOf('d')
moment("2021-03-03T00:00:00.000")     
moment("2022-03-03T23:59:59.999")
```

Alex.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! The problem is that system users enter the start date and expiration date of a document, and the duration must be visible. Adding that millisecond might be a solution, but I was looking for something "cleaner".

Comment: @AlessioMarchi You can try this simple & clean way `const end = moment(new Date('2022-03-03')).add('1', 'days')` to achieve your goal. Have a look on my solution i have posted.

Comment: yes, like @RashedRahat says it's sufficent to use `.add(1, 'd')` at end date.
`const end = moment('2022-03-03').add('1', 'd')`